# Have a Key Error on Web-Scraping by using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get data and export to CSV which I have main URL page and second URL main page.
Now I'm trying to get "18.111" and "98.111" from this html class:

```
<img class="aaa" alt="map" data-track-id="static-map" width="97" height="142" src="https://websitewithdetailsD&amp;width=194&amp;height=284&amp;lat=18.111&amp;lon=98.111&amp;level=15&amp;returnImage=true">
```

which my code is

```
for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('img',{"class":"aaa"}, src=True):
     parsed_url = urlparse(gps['src'])
     mykeys = ['lat', 'lon']
     gpslocation = [parse_qs(parsed_url.query)[k][0] for k in mykeys]
print(gpslocation)
```

However, it has Key error on the line of 
"gpslocation = [parse_qs(parsed_url.query)[k][0] for k in mykeys]"
when I run.

The data of other parts like Name and Title worked as the html class are not too complex.
I would like to know which part here I have the mistake or how should I fix it.
Please help.

Comment: The URL is not in a correct format. it has no tld.

Comment: @MoonsikPark I quite new to Python and web-scraping. Could you please explain more about the tld?

Comment: `src="https://websitewithdetailsD&amp;width=194&amp;height=284&amp;lat=18.111&amp;lon=98.111&amp;level=15&amp;returnImage=true"` parse_qs can't detect the url because it has no tld like .com .net .

Comment: I'm really sorry, I shortened the url. Here is the full url:  https://api.nostramap.com/Service/V2/MoreContent/StaticMap?key=Gljvr8pJ%28H3oMgUfVnPS%29bYpaodekiGJKFbUWQ02phQgPHCsAEpu%295Sw%28Q4NVFxmp%29YUFz2sa93p%282K%28acbaav0%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D2&amp;map=StreetMapHD&amp;width=194&amp;height=284&amp;lat=18.832687&amp;lon=98.998473&amp;level=15&amp;returnImage=true  it's indicated in the html class but when I access the real web, it's an another one that can be accessed which is https://map.nostramap.com/NostraMap/?place/@18.832687,98.998473,15,The%20Barn%20Steak%20House%20At%20Hidden%20village/th

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it using split & replace as the following:

```
def get_lat_lon(tag):
    for key_value in tag.split('src')[1].split(';'):
        if 'lat' in key_value:
            lat = key_value.split('=')[1].replace('&amp','')
        if 'lon' in key_value:
            lon = key_value.split('=')[1].replace('&amp','')
    return lat, lon

lat,lon = get_lat_lon("""<img class="aaa" alt="map" data-track-id="static-map" width="97" height="142" src="https://websitewithdetailsD&amp;width=194&amp;height=284&amp;lat=18.111&amp;lon=98.111&amp;level=15&amp;returnImage=true">"""
)
print 'lat: ' + lat
print 'lon: ' + lon
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite new for python and this. It has some problem with SyntaxError (invalid syntax) on "def get_lat_lon(tag)" I do not sure whether it's my mistake that I put it in some wrong way. Since, I am scaping data from several pages in a website, how could I turn the format to not specify each of the url in python code? (e.g. indicate class only)

Comment: I'm not sure whether I put all info you may need. I if anything you would like me to add more, plase let me know. Here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13N6qn8pUyIdOu7sYiDUF-yC7iVQIqn-bqK3A3yTVbKQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to remove all the indent from the lines after the line containing return.

Comment: I've updated the info. Please check my given link again.

Comment: The updated image of worksheet is in the second page of google doc. If I don't get it wrong, you mean me to remove the indent all lines under the Return?